# Format a text file by regex match and replace

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, sublimetext

I have a text file that looks like the following:

```
   Chanelle
   Jettie
   Winnie
   Jen
   Shella
   Krysta
   Tish
   Monika
   Lynwood
   Danae
   2649
   2466
   2890
   2224
   2829
   2427
   2816
   2648
   2833
   2453
```

I need to make it look like this

```
   Chanelle   2649
   Jettie     2466
   ...        ...
```

I tried a lot on sublime editor but couldn't figure out the regex to do that. Can somebody demonstrate if it can be done.

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to do this with just regex. Do you have a programming language avaliable? You could do something like `/^\s*\d+$/m` to   pull all the number reference then split the left over alpha references (`explode("\n", $string);` in PHP) and match them 1 - 1 to build a new file.

Comment: yes I know multiple languages, but I am trying to accomplish this using regex only. As you said, maybe it can't be done with regex alone

Comment: you actually don't need a regex for that...

Answer (score 3):

I tested the following in Notepad++ but it should work universally.

Use this as the search string:

```
(?:(\s+[A-Za-z]+)(\r?\n))((?:\s*[A-Za-z]*\r?\n)+)\s+(\d+)
```

and this as the replacement:

```
$1 $4$2$3
```

Running a replace with it once will do one line at a time, if you run it multiple times it'll continue to replace lines until there are no matching lines left.

Alternatively, you can use this as the replacement if you want to have the values aligned by tabs, but it's not going to match in all cases:

```
$1\t\t$4$2$3
```

Comment: Unfortunately, no match on sublime, notepad++, and online regex sites :(

Comment: This works fine for me in ST3. Make sure you have regex matching on, then keep hitting `Replace` until all the numbers are transposed.

Answer (score 2):

While the regex [answer by SeinopSys](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37736460/1426065) will work, you don't need a regex to do this - instead, you can take advantage of Sublime's multiple cursors.

1. Place your cursor at the beginning of line 1, then hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> to select all the names.

[image]

2. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> (**`Selection -> Split into Lines`**) to split the selection into lines.

[image]

3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to copy.
4. Place your cursor on line 11 (the first number line) and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> (Windows/OS X) or <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>↓</kbd> (Linux) to place a cursor at the beginning of each number line.

[image]

5. Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> to paste the names before the numbers.

[image]

6. You can now delete the names at the top and you're all set. Alternatively, you could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to cut the names in step 3.

Comment: In theory Shift+Click should work too in case the name list is too long to select with Shift+Down within a reasonable time frame

Comment: @SeinopSys that's true, I just used Shift-Down in this example because of the small size of the list.